# error while retreiving variable while working with stack navigator in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native . I am unable to make the stack navigator work when user logged in. I am unable to pass the auth variable mention in the below code. When i want to retreive the auth variable it gives and error 'cant find auth variable'.

```
       import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; 
       import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
       import Login from './login';
       import SInfo from 'react-native-sensitive-info';

       const Index = Login;

       const Home = HomeScreen;


       SInfo.getItem('token', {
       sharedPreferencesName: 'mySharedPrefs',
       keychainService: 'myKeychain'}).then(value => {

         const auth = value;    


      });

     if(auth!='')
    {
       const Index = HomeScreen;
     }


       const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
       Index: { screen: Index },
       Home: { screen: Home },
       });


      const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
      export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` is block specific so you cannot access `auth` variable outside of block.

To access `auth` variable you have to make it either `var` or check your condition inside block.

Comment: did that .. but didn't worked for me..  thanks for the reply

Comment: SInfo.getItem is your async method. So even if you declare auth as var wont work. Instead check your logic inside then()

Comment: If it is working, please accept and upvote the answer.  Thank you..:)

Comment: What issue you are getting now?

Comment: I managed it to work.. As i was calling value from async function which returns only promise (resolve, reject) .I stored resolve to true or false and returned it to another function.  Then i use constructor variable to get the response of that function.